# retreive SiteCollection Secondary Administrator using CSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, csom

I am unable to retrieve "secondarycontact" value from **Site** object. I am using client dll v16.0.4002.1211 against SharePoint 2013. my code is here :

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
Site site = context.Site;
context.Load(site, s => s.Owner, s => s.SecondaryContact);
context.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine(site.Owner.Title);
Console.WriteLine(site.SecondaryContact.Title);
```

Exception:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Field or property "SecondaryContact
" does not exist.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream res
ponseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at ConsoleApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\mani-3065\Docum
ents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication\ConsoleApplication\Program.c
s:line 63
```

In msdn blog its given that Secondary contact property is available for SharePoint 2013. Can anyone help? thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can only get these info using powershell. Powershell command :Get-SPSite http://sharepoint/sites/test1 | select url, owner, secondarycontact

Comment: Its given in msdn blog here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site.secondarycontact.aspx and i have seen some code samples in other blogs too

Answer (score 1):

First fetch the primary administrator using CSOM :  Context.Site.Owner

Then use rest api to get sitecollection administrators
"https://siteurl/_api/web/siteusers?$filter=IsSiteAdmin%20eq%20true"

Except the site owner remaining all users are secondary site collection administrators

Answer (score 0):

You need to install new **NuGet package** for that in Visual Studio. It's new update for SharePoint CSOM.

Please follow the steps given [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2015/04/10/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-office-365.aspx).

Hope this is what you want.:)

Comment: can i use this dll for SharePoint 2013 on-premise? because its given as ''Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM''

Comment: I think YES. Because they have mentioned that in that blog.

Comment: I tried using the new package. but the problem persists. Still same exception is thrown